# unable to take mongodb dump using mongodump command

Tags: mongodb, dump

While trying to take mongodump, I am getting the below error

```
mongodump --host 127.0.0.1 --port 27017 --db csgdb
2018-12-12T05:16:39.928+0000    Failed: error connecting to db server: 
no reachable servers
```

Even not able to login to mongo shell

```
mongo --port 27017
MongoDB shell version v3.4.7
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27018/
2018-12-12T05:14:54.161+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: network error 
while attempting to run command 'isMaster' on host '127.0.0.1:27018'  :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Any help?

Comment: Anything interesting in the log?

Comment: You can get log path from mongod.conf file

Comment: Have you altered the output? It seems unusual that you are passing `27017` as the port and getting a `mongo` shell connection attempt to `27018`. Given network errors connecting to a local server, it looks like you have specified an incorrect port or the `mongod` server is not currently running. Note: if your `mongod` server is indeed running on the default port (`27017`) you do not have to specify `--port`. If you can work out how to connect via the `mongo` shell, you should also be able to connect with `mongodump`.